# What does this mean? TypeError: now is not a function. (In 'now()', 'now' is undefined)

Tags: react-native

I'm setting up React Native and downloaded Expo Go but when I open the app this message pops up and I'm not able to continue working.

Edit: Using a Windows computer on Windows 10 and iPhone 11 for Expo Go

```
TypeError: now is not a function. (In 'now()', 'now' is undefined)
at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:95:4 in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:141:19 in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules\@react-native\polyfills\error-guard.js:49:36 in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:370:8 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:113:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Comment: Device or emulator do you use?

Comment: Windows 10 and an iPhone 11 @HazratGafulov